# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol, but the function is defined?

Tags: c++, sdl

For reference, I am working on a project using SDL. I have the Multibyte character set enabled, the Windows subsystem set for the Linker, and, I believe, all the .lib and .dll files pointed to correctly. In the top of my main I have `#include "SDL.h"`

So I have a struct that contains an enum for raw inputs:

RawInputConstants.h:

```
struct RawInput
{
    enum RawInputButton
    {
        RAW_INPUT_KEY_W,
        RAW_INPUT_KEY_A,
        RAW_INPUT_KEY_S,
        RAW_INPUT_KEY_D
    };
}
```

I include this to my helper function header and define the following function in the .cpp.

InputHelper.cpp:

```
bool ConvertSDLKeyToRawButton(SDL_Event &event, RawInput::RawInputButton &button)
{
    switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
    {
    case SDLK_w:        button = RawInput::RawInputButton::RAW_INPUT_KEY_W;     break;
    case SDLK_a:        button = RawInput::RawInputButton::RAW_INPUT_KEY_A;     break;
    case SDLK_s:        button = RawInput::RawInputButton::RAW_INPUT_KEY_S;     break;
    case SDLK_d:        button = RawInput::RawInputButton::RAW_INPUT_KEY_D;     break;

    default:            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

In main, I include the InputHelper and try to say:

```
RawInput::RawInputButton button;
if (ConvertSDLKeyToRawButton (event, button))
```

I am receiving:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ConvertSDLKeyToRawButton(union SDL_Event &,enum RawInput::RawInputButton)" (?ConvertSDLKeyToRawButton@@YA_NAATSDL_Event@@W4RawInputButton@RawInput@@@Z) referenced in function _SDL_main
```

It seems like it is complaining that it doesn't know what to do with ConvertSDLKeyToRawButton, but I'm not sure why, as I thought the struct was exposed by including the header file it is present in. Is this not the case? Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Pay more attention to the error.

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=name+mangling

Comment: Just to clarify....you didn't show the _declaration_ but according to the error the second argument is taken by _value_ not by reference which would indicate that the definition does not match the declaration,

Comment: Yep, I see exactly what I did now, and it was pretty dopey. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the reference from the second parameter of ConvertSDLKeyToRawButton